# BufferedReader in java, always throws exception

Tags: java

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

try{
    BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println ("1..case1 | 2..case2");
    String ch=Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());       //user input for switch
    System.out.println (ch);
    bf.close();
    switch(ch) {                  //userinput ch variable switch in case
        case 1 :
            String data=bf.readLine();
            bf.close();
            System.out.println(data);
            break;
        case 2 :            
            System.out.print ("Enter Key ");
            String key=bf.readLine();
            bf.close();
            System.out.println(key);
            break;
        default :
            System.out.println ("wrong choice");        
  }
  }

  catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println ("io error");
  }
  bf.close();

}
```

//every time after 1st user input it goes to partcular matching case, but at the next user input it throws an exception.

please help..
thanks in advance..

Comment: Whats the exception? Post stack trace

Comment: You're trying to read a line _after_ the reader is closed. Can't do that.

Comment: so when should i use .close() function..

Comment: Add the exception trace here

Comment: @sanjitguin The documentation (and common sense) would dictate *after you're done using it*.

Comment: Does this `String ch=Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());` even compile?

Comment: sorry about "String ch=Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine())" it was "int ch=Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine())". i made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a good habit to close in finally block else use try with resource if you are using java7 or higher version

See this [mkyongs example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/try-with-resources-example-in-jdk-7/)

Also this line is wrong    `String ch=Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());`  make it to `int`

you are converting bf.readLIne() to int and storing in string,This is wrong.

Another error is you are closing `bf.close();` after the try-catch block so compiler may complain

Complete working code

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    BufferedReader bf=null;

    try{
         bf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println ("1..case1 | 2..case2");
        int ch=Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());       //user input for switch
        System.out.println (ch);

        switch(ch){                  //userinput ch variable switch in case
            case 1 :
                String data=bf.readLine();

                System.out.println(data);
                break;
            case 2 :            
                System.out.print ("Enter Key ");
                String key=bf.readLine();

                System.out.println(key);
                break;
            default :
                System.out.println ("wrong choice");        
      }
    } catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println ("io error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            bf.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    }
```

Comment: Please provide an answer with better formatting, this is difficult to understand.

Comment: @AlexisLeclerc I am using mobile so feeling hard to format,though I have tried but it remains the same

Comment: I can understand using this on a mobile can be challenging. Here, I gave you a helping hand :)

Comment: @AlexisLeclerc Thanks but your edit was rejected by community